# Is there a way to know if a "destroy" called to a model comes from a "dependent" relation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, destroy

Given a Product Model that has many Colors

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :colors, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and a Color Model that belongs to Product, with an `after_destroy` that destroy the product if it have no more colors.

```
class Color < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  after_destroy do |color|
    product = color.product
    product.destroy! if product.colors.count.zero?
  end
end
```

When I destroy a Color, or even all Colors everything works well.
But when I try to destroy a Product it raise a: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotDestroyed (Failed to destroy the record)`

on this line, inside Color model: `product.destroy! if product.colors.count.zero?`

After a bit of test I think it's related to that circular destroy that it's created between Product and Colors. Is there a way to spot if the Color object is being destroyed by the "has_many" dependency or not?

Comment: you can try to check if `product.marked_for_destruction?`

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 callbacks defined for associations (before_add, after_add, before_remove, and after_remove). You probably want after_remove:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :colors, dependent: :destroy, after_remove: :cleanup_product

  def cleanup_product(color)
    color.product.destroy if color.product.colors.empty?
  end
end
```